# Eager Loading with LinqKit and EFCore

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, linqkit

B"H

C#sharps inclusion of linq right into the language is one of its most powerful features.
It is also what makes Entity Framework such an enticing option for working with a database.

Unfortunately due to typing restrictions its often difficult to create centralized expressions to use throughout your project/solution.

One answer to that question is LinqKit. This was working great for me in EF 6.x.
However when I moved to EF Core, I am facing a showstopper.

Instead of properly compiled expressions which should then be converted into SQL statement. What I am getting are function like expressions which don't include their sub expressions in the SQL that they generate. Instead they create `AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.EnumerableAdapter`s which .Net tries to execute (out of an async context) when you access the `IEnumerables` a few lines later.

So the **question** is: How do I get EF Core to execute the entire expression as one SQL statement and return a complete materialized object?

Given two classes

```
    class OrderItemDTO
    {
        public string OrderItemName { get; set; }
    }
    class OrderDTO
    {
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItemDTO> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to create a global expressions somewhere

```
    public static Expression<Func<Order, OrderDTO>> ToDTO = x => new OrderDTO
    {
        OrderName = x.Name,
        OrderItems = x.Items.Select(y => new OrderItemDTO { OrderItemName = y.Name })
    };
```

Which I would then use somewhere as `var orders = await db.Orders.AsExpandable().Select(ToDTO).ToListAsync();`
Expecting a fully materialized OrderDTO.

Instead what I get is a DTO with OrderItems as a `AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.EnumerableAdapter` which causes a race condition when executed

Comment: `db.AsExpandable()` doesn't sound correct. `OrderItems = x.Items.Select(y => new OrderItemDTO { OrderItemName = y.Name })` does not compile (`ICollection<OrderItemDTO>` cannot be assigned from `IEnumerable<OrderItemDTO>`). [Adding .ToList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries) at the end would probably solve both compile and runtime issue.

Answer (score 1):

Call `AsQueryable()` and then `ToList()` on your inner collections - EF will then be able to correctly treat this as full projection:

```
public static Expression<Func<Order, OrderDTO>> ToDTO = x => new OrderDTO
{
    OrderName = x.Name,
    OrderItems = x.Items.AsQueryable().Select(y => new OrderItemDTO { OrderItemName = y.Name }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: Why the call to `AsQueriable()`?